# how to install multiple instances of apache on a single windows7 machine?

Tags: apache, windows-7, xampp

I want to run multiple instances of apache on one single machine? How to go about it? I am using xampp.. any kind of help would be appreciated. thanx
I installed one more xampp in a separate directory, but only one xampp control panel can run at a time.

Comment: Serverfault candidate? Might have more server-specific help there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give each instance a different port number. I am presently running two instances of Apache (ports 81 and 8080) and one of IIS (port 80). The Apache instances were installed by other products (Subversion, etc).

Comment: did u just ran the installer twice and assigned different port numbers??

Comment: I didn't install Xampp.  It was Subversion and TeamCity.  Both install an instance of Apache.  You could install Xampp in different directories and then edit the ports.conf file.  See http://developer.mindtouch.com/en/kb/Run_Apache_on_a_Different_Port for details.

Answer (score 0):

You may also try the [USB versions of XAMPP](http://portableapps.com/apps/development/xampp).

Answer (score 0):

We have to use multiple xampp instance for many reasons. For example, difference PHP version.

you have to use difference port number for each xamp instance
Instance #1 default port number is 80 change to 81.
Instance #2 default port number is 80 change to 82.

DONT forget to change ssl port in apache\conf\extra\httpd-ssl.conf.

Instance #1 default is port number 80 change to 81, ssl default is 443 change to 444

Instance #2 default is port number 80, change to 82, ssl default is 443 change to 445, etc